# Cannot resolve symbol 'GeofencingClient'

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

empece a trabajar en el ámbito de Android y trabajo en una app que usa geofencing, usando la documentación de google me encuentro con una clase que no puedo usarla "**GeofencingClient**" y no se cual dependencia se requiere, investigue en Internet pero no la encuentro, anexo un pedazo de código.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente no puedes acceder a la clase ya que no tienes agregado el `import` adecuado para la clase `GeofencingClient`:

```
 private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;
```

debes agregar el import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
```

y obviamente en las dependencias de tu archivo `build.grade` definir `play-services-location` :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

}
```

Comment: es mi pregunta, cual es el import necesario, no lo encuentro en ningun lado ^^

Comment: Importante definir también dentro de tu build.gradle:  "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:<version>" para que puedas usar el import de la clase GeofencingClient @Sara